# Saving object with child objects from different context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm currently working on an app using EF 4.1 Code First and have a question about how to save a new object with child objects from another context. The Context is stored in request mode.

I create a new object called 'Vacancy'. The user is then prompted to add locations to the Vacancy's collection of locations. The locations are pulled through the context and preferably  I would like to avoid saving locations added to the Vacancy back to the database until the user is finished which could potentially be after several postbacks.

Problem is that the Locations are from a context that does no longer exist so trying to save my vacancy will throw an error.

I'm sure this is a common problem and I hope there is a good way to handle this.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must detach each entity you want to store (probably in session) among multiple requests.

```
context.Entry(loadedEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

You should be also able to completely avoid this if you turn off proxy creation for loading of these entities and load them as no tracking.

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; // This should generally be enough
var loadedEntity = context.Entities.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(...);
```

Be aware that during the save you will have to tell EF that those entities are existing one by again correctly setting their state otherwise EF will try to insert them again.

Comment: I have quite a few tables that simply store semi static information. StatusTypes, Locations, Currencies etc etc some of which could be enums when EF support it. These are being return from a static service class as: 'GetAllLocations()'and similar. If I detach the returned objects in this Method and add some or all of them to a newly created object would I have to attach all the child objects manually when saving the parent object to avoid double entries?

Comment: Yes you will have to handle that. That is the cost of working with EF this way.

Comment: Hmm perhaps I should read and understand your whole answer before commenting seeing as that is exactly what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You mention, 'working with ef this way'. do you have a link or reference to alternative way to handle this using code first?












F

Comment: Alternative is not to use detached entities but it leads to very intensive communication with a database.